# 配布したプログラムのデータベースとして利用しているXMLを変更する方法

Tags: c#, xml

C#でWindows Form Applicationを作成して実行ファイルを客先に以前リリースしました。そのプログラムはXMLをデータベースとして利用しております。

今回、プログラムに機能追加を行いました。exeのみの変更です。exeのみリリースして設置してもらう予定ですが、既に稼働している客先のXMLには変更を加える必要があります。

この場合は、普通どのような手段で行うのがよいのでしょうか？バージョンアップのパッチをリリースして、それを実行するとXMLの不整合の部分を修正してくれるようなものをイメージするのですが。。

追加：
今回の変更で、ユーザーがあるテンプレートを追加していく機能があるのですが、そのテンプレート上の最初から登録されている初期項目が追加となったのです。ですので、この新しい初期項目は、新しくテンプレートを登録する場合は追加されているのですが、今回の修正前に既に登録されたテンプレートに関しては、新しい初期項目は追加されません。それぞれのテンプレートに登録された項目の情報は、XMLに保存してあります。ですので、既存テンプレートの項目に新しい項目を追加したいというのが、今回の要望です。

exeのプログラムに、起動時などに毎回その初期項目が存在しないテンプレートがあった場合、初期項目を追加し、そうでなければ何もしない。というような処理を入れるしかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 何故、以前リリースしたXMLを変更する必要があるのですか？
XMLは構造的データを表現する文字列の書式であって、データベースではありません。
「XMLをデータベースとして利用」という所で基本的な設計が破綻していませんか？

Comment: XMLをデータベースとして利用するのが正しいかどうかはこの際別として、データーベースとして使っています。なぜ以前リリースしたXMLを変更する必要があるかについては、OPに追記しましたので、ご確認ください。

Comment: exeのプログラムで御指摘のXMLを読み書きしているのでしょうね．新しい機能追加をしたプログラムを使っていただく際に、旧のXMLフォーマットから新のXMLフォーマットに変換するXSLTスタイルシートを作って対応するのではいかがですか？このレベルのプログラムならXSLT 1.0で書いて別の簡単なコマンドラインのC#から呼び出すもので済むはずと思います．

Comment: 起動時にファイルチェックして確認メッセージの後にコンバートするとか、別途コンバータプログラムを用意して、手順のマニュアル渡して実行して貰うくらいしかない気はしますが。

Comment: XML にデータを保存すること自体はあり得る話だと思いますが、「データベース」と表現してしまうのはやや語弊がある気がします。

Comment: @radian 起動時にファイルチェックしてコンバートすることにしました。確認メッセージは出しませんが。

Answer (score 1):

私の場合は、XMLにバージョン番号項目を埋め込んでその値からデータの修正が必要かを判断し処理する、という実装をしていました。
まだバージョン番号が存在しない場合は初期バージョンであると判断します。
基本的にアプリ起動時に毎回処理します。

新しい項目が追加されただけというのであれば、別の方法もあります。
データを読み込んだときに項目があればそれを返し、ない場合は既定値を返すようにします。
この方法ではXMLの修正の必要はありません。